# Prestashop shipping error: There are no carriers that deliver to the address you selected

Tags: prestashop, shopping-cart, carrier

[image: prestashop front office]

I have installed and added the products to the shop. But for testing when I tried to checkout, it says "There are no carriers that deliver to the address you selected.".
I need

> 1. All cash on delivery
> 2. Our own shipping
> 3. Flat shipping fee say 2USD.

How can I achieve the above requirements?

Comment: I have this issue too, but it only appears in Internet Explorer version 8. I don't have this problem in Firefox. I did notice that Firefox adds the default shipping costs, whereas IE8 doesn't. Could this be linked to the issue? I'm using Prestashop version 1.5.4.1, didn't have this issue in my previous Prestashop version.

Comment: Prestashop 1.6.0.9: I get the same address error, when there is no carrier for the product because of the product's weight. even that the address is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Prestashop 1.6.1.4
Go to **Shipping --> Carriers**

and select "**your carrier name**" and click to edit it.

In 2nd tab "**shipping locations and costs**" tab slect your ranges. (Which you select during prestashop installation)

or if you don't know then simply click on "**All**" ranges.

Answer (score 3):

This message is displayed when there are no carriers assigned to a zone at which your selected country resides. Please note that in PS, you have to select Zones for which the carrier will be available. And you have to make sure that the country for which you provides shipping are in those zones.

Lets say you have two carriers A and B and also consider Pakistan, which is in Asia. Now, if no carrier has Asia zone, then for Pakistan, you will get that message.

Now if you have assigned carrier A to Asia zone , then only A will be displayed to Pakistan.

And if you have assigned carrier A and B both to Asia zone, then for Pakistan, both will be shown.

I hope this will help.

Thank you

Comment: Thnx Altaf..but I have already chosen `Asia`,and my address belongs to `Assam` which is in `India`. I am sending you a snapshot, please check.